# Access local application data in a Universal Windows Applicaiton

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm trying to port the following to a UWP app:

`var localAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
string spotlightPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(localAppData, "Packages\\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\\LocalState\\Assets");`

It look like ApplicationData.LocalFolder is exactly what I need: "Gets the root folder in the local app data store."

(from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx)

I can't work out how to access it though:
`var localAppData = ApplicationData.LocalFolder;`

Gives the following error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ApplicationData.LocalFolder'

Comment: with a windows universal app, you don't have direct access to the file system.

Comment: What's this property for then?

Comment: you're using this inside a method right?

Comment: are you using ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder?

Comment: That works - it gives me the App's LocalFolder not the User's one unfortunately. Maybe what I want isn't possible.

Comment: You mean you want to access the place where other packages are stored? or just your package?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108923/discussion-between-absolutesith-and-boden-garman).

Comment: If you want to access you package location then use  Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("YourFolderName")

Answer (score 0):

use this to access local folder of your app:

```
var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get the path for for the app's settings and files:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

string ThePath = localFolder.Path;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/apps/hh700361(v=win.10)